# I want to upload images to S3 from react-admin using fastapi endpoint

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, fastapi, react-admin, image-upload

I am creating a backend API with FastAPI. I want to use this endpoint to upload images to S3 from the admin screen I am creating with React-Admin and INSERT the image URL and other column values into the database.

If the POST is successful, the response will be as follows.

```
{
  "product_name": "test",
  "detail": "test",
  "obj_url": "{ URL }"
}
```

The following is the error on the backend side when posting and the payload when posting with React-Admin.

```
// POST /products/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
{
    product_name: "test",
    detail: "<p>test</p>",
    file: {
        rawFile: {
            path: "test.jpg"
        },
        name: "test.jpg",
        url: "blob:{ URL }"
    }
}
```

```
// Shown as 422(response)
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "product_name"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        },
        {
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "detail"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought that the above error would occur because the API is nested when posting with react-admin, so I tried changing the dataprovider, but couldfast not get it to work.
If anyone has a solution, I would appreciate your help.

Sorry if my weird English is hard to understand.

### FastAPI

```
# routers/post.py
@router.post("/")
def post_product(product_name: str, detail: str, file: UploadFile = File(None)):
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = os.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION")
    AWS_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_BUCKET_NAME")

    s3_bucket = AWS_BUCKET_NAME
    s3_dir = "test-img"
    region_name = AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

    s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name=region_name)

    response = s3.put_object(
        Body=file.file, Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=f"{s3_dir}/{file.filename}"
    )

    file_url = "https://%s.s3.%s.amazonaws.com/%s" % (
        s3_bucket,
        region_name,
        s3_dir + "/" + file.filename,
    )

    insert = {"product_name": product_name, "detail": detail, "obj_url": file_url}
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="postgres",
        user="postgres",
        password="Password",
        host="localhost",
        port=5432,
    )
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO products (product_name, detail, obj_url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
        (insert["product_name"], insert["detail"], insert["obj_url"]),
    )
    conn.commit()

    response = {"product_name": product_name, "detail": detail, "obj_url": file_url}

    return response
```

### React-Admin

```
// App.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Admin, fetchUtils, Resource } from "react-admin";
import { PostList, PostEdit, PostCreate } from "./components/Posts";
import { ProfileList, ProfileEdit } from "./components/Profiles";
import { ProductList, ProductEdit, ProductShow } from "./components/Products";
import { ProductCreate } from './components/Products'

import jsonServerProvider from "ra-data-json-server";
import simpleRestProvider from "ra-data-simple-rest";

import "./App.css";

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider("http://localhost:8000", fetchUtils.fetchJson);

function App() {
  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="posts"    list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} />
      <Resource name="profiles" list={ProfileList} edit={ProfileEdit} />
      <Resource name="products" list={ProductList} edit={ProductEdit} create={ProductCreate} show={ProductShow} />
    </Admin>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// in src/components/Posts/index.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import {
    List,
    Show,
    Edit,
    Create,
    Datagrid,
    TextField,
    NumberField,
    ImageField,
    SimpleForm,
    TextInput,
    NumberInput,
    ImageInput,
    required,
    SimpleShowLayout
} from "react-admin";
import { RichTextInput } from 'ra-input-rich-text';

export const ProductCreate = () => (
    <Create>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="product_name" validate={[required()]} fullWidth />
            <RichTextInput source="detail" />
            <ImageInput
                // multiple={true}
                source="file"
                label="Related pictures"
                accept="image/*"
            >
                <ImageField source="url" title="name" />
            </ImageInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

### Data Provider(Some parts are omitted.)

```
// index.ts
// https://github.com/typicode/json-server

export default (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson): DataProvider => ({
    getList: (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
            _sort: field,
            _order: order,
            _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
            _end: page * perPage,
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

        return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => {
            if (!headers.has('x-total-count')) {
                throw new Error(
                    'The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
                );
            }
            return {
                data: json,
                total: parseInt(
                    headers.get('x-total-count').split('/').pop(),
                    10
                ),
            };
        });
    },
    create: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
        })),
});
```

Comment: The body of the 422 error response will contain information about which validation of input data that fails - and if any required information is missing.

Comment: @MatsLindh
Thank you for your comment.
Sorry for the image, but is this information here?
https://gyazo.com/10410a66fc6d6a90fad853766212ce1c

Comment: No, that is just the stack trace of the request. Go to the "Network" tab, then look at the failing request (shown as 422), and look at the Response or Preview tabs to see the body of the response.

Comment: @MatsLindh
I had looked at that as well, but it was left out of what I was going to post as information. Sorry about that. I added it to the question as shown as 422.
It is true that I have entered these two items in react-admin and then posted, but it points out that the values are missing. Is there another factor for this? Also, no image information is coming through in the response.

Comment: It's saying that it expects the two parameters as query parameters - since you haven't included any information about how you're sending the request to the FastAPI part, it's hard to say - but I'm guessing you want these to be HTTP Form values instead (or if you want them to be a JSON body, make sure that you encode the file you're sending as base64 as a field inside the JSON body); You can use either `product_name: str = Body()` or `product_name: str = Form()` to tell FastAPI to get the value from a JSON body or from a HTTP form respectively.

Comment: @MatsLindh
I am late, but I have posted an excerpt from the CREATE portion of the data provider's program.
I apologize for the long delay, but I would like to confirm that my understanding is correct.
The image file to be sent on the front end side is encoded in base64. Or I make the values of the two fields HTTP form values and use product_name: str = Body() or product_name: str = Form() in the post method of the FastAPI to get the values respectively.
Are you suggesting that one of these methods might be the solution?